# How does the sharing feature on Dropbox allow you to send private messages to Facebook friends?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to implement something similar to the share feature on Dropbox that allows you to send an invite to Facebook friends.

https://www.dropbox.com/share

You will need to log in/ create an account and have a shared folder to see it.

The feature only ever shows one Facebook dialogue which is to give it's app permissions - I don't know how it even manages to send a private message - from the research I've done this isn't even possible, and secondally, I don't know how it manages to achieve it without using a Facebook dialogue - it uses it's own modal box.

So far I have managed to pull a list of Facebook friends into a jquery ui autocomplete but don't know how to now send the private message to the selected friend now that I have their id.

The only way I could think of how to do this was to send the user an email at id@facebook.com but don't know how you attach the image, description, link etc like you do to a normal wall/timeline post.

I was hoping some of the Facebook experts here could offer their thoughts and opinions?

Comment: What permission(s) does it require when you add the app? Where do the messages arrive to? Your chat pops up or to the top messages icon?

Comment: Trying to remember the permissions(I apologise, I am on my phone) I can remember that one is offline access. The message goes to the top messages icon, the inbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that I'm aware of that enables an app to send private messages to non app users is via the [Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).
For that you need to ask for the "xmpp_login" which:

> Provides applications that integrate with Facebook Chat the ability to
>   log in users

([Permissions Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/))

When you have that you can become a xmpp client of the user, get *presence* updates from the user friends (and with that you can know which friends of the user are online) and you can send messages to the friends on the user's behalf, but also here facebook asks that the message will come from the user which is probably the modal dialog in dropbox.

This api is not a simple one because it requires your app to have an xmpp client.
There are some client implementations (flash and even [js clients](http://strophe.im/)) but I have no experience with that, on the other hand I can tell you from experience that managing xmpp per logged in client can be tricky so try to avoid it unless you really need it.

You can remove the app you have for dropbox in facebook and then add it again, then you'll see what the permissions are and see if indeed they ask for the "xmpp_login" permission, if not please let me know what they do ask for.

---

## Edit

You got me intrigued and so I tried it myself, and you're right they are not asking for the "xmpp_login" permission, only "offline_access" and "publish_stream".

I can't explain how they manage to pull that off, they don't do it in the client, I can see the request going to their servers.
The best guess I have is that they have special privileges from facebook, I know that they do that with some companies.

If I'm right about this, for you there are two options: use the send dialog or use the chat api.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will have a look. Not sure if this is what dropbox is doing, it's really got me stumped how they are able to do it

Comment: Thanks once again, much appreciated. I think you could be right about special privileges because I don't think it is possible without using the send dialogue and especially when it concerns private messages, it's a shame though, I was really hoping I could create an almost identical sharing app. Well done Dropbox though, never seen anything like it!

Comment: If it's that important for you then just ask for the chat permissions and use that. It can be done, we're doing something very similar using the chat api.

Answer (score 1):

In Dropbox they are sending an email to the particular user with their facebook email address (eg.username@facebook.com)

You can see this email address in your facebook General Account Settings. and you can see this note below it which says:

"Your Facebook email is based on your public username. Email sent to this address goes to Facebook Messages."

You just need to retrive the user's email id and their friend's username....

and you can send attachments along with it as well....!!

Comment: Just saw that this behavior will be changing and messages will be sent to the user's primary email address instead of Messages: https://www.facebook.com/help/703286543026907